# Replacing symbolic strings in R

Tags: r

I have read.csv file including a column with which I want to replace two strings with values 0 and 1.

Here's my `dput(head(data))`:

```
structure(list(Age = c(39L, 50L, 38L, 53L, 28L, 37L), 
    Salary = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" <=50K", 
    " >50K"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Age", "Salary"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The Salary column currently has "<=50K" and ">50K", and I want the former to be replaced with 0 and the latter with 1. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
> transform(data, Salary=c("<=50K"=0, ">50K"=1)[as.character(Salary)])
```

However, I think there's a problem in that the strings contain mathematical symbols. I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '<=' in "transform(data, Salary=c(<="
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try instead: `transform(data, Size = (Size == ">1") +0L)` (not tested in absence of sample data)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error.  You may have to show an example dataset using `dput`.

Comment: The error message doesn't show any `"` around `<=` which makes me suspicious.

Comment: @akrun My problem can be completely replicated using this dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data where the final column is either <=50 or >50. How would I make these 0 and 1, respectively? I hope this helps

Comment: @Phibert My comment was based on `set.seed(24);
 data <- data.frame(Size=sample(c('<=1', 2, '>1'), 20, replace=TRUE));
 transform(data, Size=c("<=1"=0, ">1"=1)[as.character(Size)])`

Comment: @akrun When I do that with the data I linked above, it replaces everything with NA. Is this perhaps because I'm using data <- read.csv() rather than data <- data.frame()

Comment: @Phibert Actually, in the link showed, (I assume you are referring to the last column. ) `sum(data$V15== '<=1')
[1] 0; sum(data$V15== '>1')
[1] 0`

Comment: @akrun when I use `sum(data$V15== ' <=50K')[1] 0`  I get the error `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "sum(data$V15== ' <=50K')[1] 0"`

Comment: @Phibert I couldn't reproduce it though `sum(data$V15== ' <=50K')
[1] 24720`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link provided, there are only two "unique" values for the last column.  One way to recode the values to "0,1" would be to convert the column to "factor" and coerce to "numeric" (`as.numeric`).  This will give "1,2" based on the levels of the factor, subtract "1" and get the correct recoded value , i.e. "0,1".

```
  unique(data$V15)
  #[1] " <=50K" " >50K" 
  data$V15 <- as.numeric(factor(data$V15))-1
  head(data$V15,20)
  #[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

#### data

```
  url <- 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data'

  library(RCurl)
  x <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
  data <- read.csv(textConnection(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)
```

Comment: Using this exactly, I get NA for every entry in the final column

Comment: @Phibert Could you show the dput of `head(data)` and update it in your post?

Comment: I've added this to my post. I'm only interested in Age and Salary, so have removed all other columns

Comment: @Phibert Based on your dput output, `as.numeric(data$Salary)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1`.  , Salary is already a factor with 2 levels.  So, I am not sure why you are getting different results.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something. This also gives me an error. Apologies for my lack of knowledge here

Comment: @Phibert I am commenting based on your dput output.. It couldn't be wrong.  I use `R 3.1.2`

Comment: It just says `Error: unexpected numeric constant in "as.numeric(data$Salary) [1] 1"` when I use `as.numeric(data$Salary) [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1`. I also use R 3.1.2

Comment: @Phibert The code should be `as.numeric(data$Salary)` and the rest is just the output I get

Comment: @Phibert I guess you are new to R.  Once you get used to R, this will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since Salary is a factor with levels:

```
> levels(data$Salary)
[1] " <=50K" " >50K"
```

try this:

```
levels(data$Salary) <- 0:1
```